# java HTTP get response after delay

Tags: java, http, get, delay

I am making a program in java that requests a certain url and gets the information I need.
I am using the Jsoup lib but I'm having trouble with one certain aspect.

How can I request a http url, wait a couple of seconds (while maintaining the connection), and then get the response? Because the site needs a couple of seconds to load the requested url, before the data is loaded onto the webpage a loading screen is displayed.
I tried the following:

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url);
Thread.sleep(10000);
Document doc = con.get();
```

But this didn't work out..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have so much experience with Jsoup but have you tried waiting for a response()? Eg Jsoup.response() and then use Document parse() on that response?